# how to disable remaining button when clicking button in visualforce page in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

<apex:commandButton id="Abutton" value="Approve" action="{!recapp}" style="padding:2px;" title="Approve" styleclass="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand" reRender="none">

<apex:param name="Approveid" value="{!s.id}" assignTo="{!apprid}"/>
</apex:commandButton>

<apex:commandButton id="Rbutton" value="Reject" action="{!recrej}" style="padding:2px;" title="Reject" styleclass="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand" reRender="three">

<apex:param name="rejectid" value="{!s.id}" assignTo="{!recjid}"/>
</apex:commandButton>

Comment: Shameless plug. Have you seen my https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/194195/799 ?

Comment: Suggestion : add code fences and the language identifier to highlight the code and make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

put `disabled="false"` or `disabled="true"` if you want to enable or disable the button, you can control this using a variable, like this `disabled={!variable}`